# Extend Vaadin File Downloader to a button with defined Click Listener

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8

File Downloader have to extend to a button like:

```
Button btn = new Button("this will download");
fileDownloader.extend(btn);
```

And it works fine.but when i define a click listener for btn, downloading doesn't work any more:

```
Button btn = new Button("click",(event) -> {//this function will be run 
});
fileDownloader.extend(btn);
```

How should  i add a click listener to this button? i want both "downloading" and any other function to be run when i click btn.

Comment: Perhaps you ClickListener must invoke some default method to trigger the download?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, using Vaadin 8.2.1. Maybe you need to provide some more code? Also I think `() -> {` in your listener is wrong. Replace it with `clickEvent -> {` even not actually using the `ClickEvent` anywhere.

Comment: I need a button to trigger the file Downloader and also call a method to close a window. How can i provide this?@pirho

Comment: Listener edited. @pirho